# Whitespace in the text for JQuery Templates creates new properties for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, whitespace, jquery-templates

I'm trying to populate a `datalist` via Jquery, however, the white space between first and last names causes only the first name to be used and the last name to be inserted as another property.

JQuery:

```
  function FillNamesDataList(names)
  {
    $("#datalistTemplate").tmpl(names).appendTo("#colleagueNames");
  }
```

Template:

```
<script id="datalistTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<option value=${name}></option>
</script>
```

If I create an array of strings that are `Why This` I get the following in my HTML: [image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show sample of your data `name`

Comment: This is just an array of objects that are strings. Ie. An array of `{name:""}`

Comment: can You create fiddle , I tested with this fiddle and it works if we have multiple words in options http://jsfiddle.net/YCQ9S/182/

Comment: Turns out I didn't encase the `${name}` in double quotes.

Comment: It it working good now

Comment: It is! Thanks for your responses. Your JSFiddle showed me that it should be encased in quotes, I'm fairly unfamiliar with JS syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append your value in double quotes:

```
<option value="${name}"></option>
```